# Tweak Election Rules for primary/election phases?

Tags: discussion, election, nominations

Some of you might have heard rumors, but right now, Science Fiction and Fantasy has [an election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) going on. We are currently at exactly 10 nominees with one day left in the nomination phase.

As it stands, if we get no more nominees, we jump right to the election phase. If we get one more nominee, we'll instead split between a primary and election phases. If we do go to a primary, it will probably be with just 11 nominees, and we will spend the next four days decided which one candidate gets eliminated.

Somehow, that seems a bit harsh on whomever that person is. While *technically* the primary is selecting the top 10 out of 11 candidates, the impression it gives is that we're picking "the worst" candidate.

Perhaps the rules could be tweaked such that the primary process isn't triggered by just having "one too many" candidate. For example, if there are more than X candidates, it triggers a primary where (.75 * X) candidates are selected. That is:

- 11 candidates -> no primary
- 12 candidates -> primary -> 9 candidate election

Comment: Then its unfair to the 12th guy. There's gotta be a line somewhere.

Comment: On the other hand, the worst candidate is often a non-serious nominee (and thus probably not very disappointed) and the main reason to hold primaries is arguably to give the voters an idea where the nominees roughly stand so that they do not waste their votes on those candidates which have no chance of winning anyway (after all, there **is** tactical voting in SE’s voting system).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: The point is that not only the 12th guy, but also the 11th and 10th guy get eliminated and thus the 12th guy is not being singled out.

Comment: Its still replacing one arbitrary line with another.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that's true, but it (to me) solves two problems: 1. You don't end up with "that one guy" who got singled out as worst, and 2. The voters are more likely to focus on "who do I want to move on?" rather than "which one do I like the least?". I know mechanically it probably works out the same but it *feels* more correct

Comment: @Wrzlprmft in that case wouldn't it make sense to have a "primary" phase all the time, even if it's just "4 days where no one can vote yet"?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: Well, the more candidates, the bigger the problem. Alternativey, you could allow voters to rank all candidates instead of just three of them – this strongly reduces (but does not eliminate) the need for tactical voting.

Comment: How often have you been on the wrong side of that line?

Comment: me, personally? This is the first time I've ever run for moderator and I don't think I'm anywhere near the line; this was more a result of discussing how the primaries worked.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102239/primaries-should-select-the-top-8-candidates :(

Comment: well then. guess this is a dupe :)